# Show category names of current page in TYPO3 8

Tags: typo3, categories, typoscript, typo3-8.x

I am trying to display the category name(s) of the current page on a TYPO3 8 installation. In TYPO3 7 it used to work like this (see below), however now I only receive a random error code and no Text output. Any Ideas?

```
lib.catclass = CONTENT
lib.catclass {

wrap = <div class="categories">|</div>

table = sys_category
select {
  pidInList = 35 // UiD of your category_page
  join = sys_category_record_mm ON(sys_category_record_mm.uid_local=sys_category.uid)
  where = sys_category_record_mm.tablenames='pages'
  andWhere.dataWrap = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = {TSFE:id}
}

renderObj = TEXT
renderObj.field = title
renderObj.wrap = <li class="category {field:title}">|</li>
renderObj.insertData = 1

}
```

The corresponding error output is as follows:

```
    An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT * FROM `sys_category` INNER JOIN `sys_category_record_mm`
    `ON(sys_category_record_mm`.`uid_local=sys_category`.`uid)` ON WHERE 
    (`sys_category`.`pid` IN (35)) AND 
    (sys_category_record_mm.tablenames='pages') AND (`sys_category`.`sys_language_uid` IN (0, -1)) AND 
((`sys_category`.`deleted` = 0) AND (`sys_category`.`t3ver_state` <= 0) AND (`sys_category`.`pid` <> -1) AND (`sys_category`.`hidden` = 0) AND (`sys_category`.`starttime` <= 1546204860) AND
 ((`sys_category`.`endtime` = 0) OR (`sys_category`.`endtime` > 1546204860)))': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '.`uid_local=sys_category`.`uid)` ON WHERE (`sys_category`.`pid` IN (35)) AND (s' at line 1
```

Comment: What is the number of your "random error code"?

Comment: You should analyze the log in `typo3temp/var/logs/`. There you should find a line with your random error code.

Comment: Another possibilty is to activate more detailed error output with `config. contentObjectExceptionHandler = 0` in your TypoScript.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I updated the original post with the error output.

Comment: Can't really figure out what this tells me though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding a space after `ON`, so:

```
join = sys_category_record_mm ON (sys_category_record_mm.uid_local=sys_category.uid)
```

Also, `andWhere` has been deprecated since TYPO3 7.1 and has been removed in 8. You need to add that to `where` and use `markers` to add the page uid. From the top of my head, that would make it:

```
lib.catclass = CONTENT
lib.catclass {
  wrap = <div class="categories">|</div>

  table = sys_category
  select {
    pidInList = 35 // UiD of your category_page
    join = sys_category_record_mm ON (sys_category_record_mm.uid_local=sys_category.uid)
    where = sys_category_record_mm.tablenames='pages' AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = ###pageuid###
    markers {
      pageuid.data = TSFE:id
    }
  }

  renderObj = TEXT
  renderObj.field = title
  renderObj.wrap = <li class="category {field:title}">|</li>
  renderObj.insertData = 1
}
```

See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/Functions/Select/#markers for more on `markers`

Comment: It now renders an output. However, it doesn't show the categories of the current page but all categories that are selected (I have 4 pages with selected categories at the moment).

Comment: `andWhere` has been deprecated since TYPO3 7.1 and has been removed in 8. You should add that part to `where` and use `markers` to add the variable. See https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/8.7/Functions/Select/#markers

Comment: thank you for the link. Can you suggest how to implement this for my case? I can't figure out how to use these markers correctly.

Comment: thank you so much! It didn't work at first but after changing "TSFE.id" to "TSFE:id" it now finally renders the correct categories for each page.

Comment: That's the disadvantage of writing something without checking it :) Glad it works now. I've edited my answer to correct the TSFE:id notation.