# TYPO3: How do I get the SYS-Category of pages in a teaser list?

Tags: typo3, typoscript, typo3-9.x

I've built a lib to put out all subpages of a page as teasers. That works so far. In this teaser I want to put out as well the sys-category of the subpages. For this I used (and modified) a typoscript what I have found here: 
[Show category names of current page in TYPO3 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53978414/show-category-names-of-current-page-in-typo3-8)

But that doesn't work - could anybody give me a hint?

Here's my code:

```
lib.newsteaser {

    20 = CONTENT
    20 {
        table = tt_content
        select {
            # Seiten-ID des Parent
            pidInList = 17
            recursive = 1
            orderBy = tx_mask_cnt_news_item_date
            where = hidden=0 AND CType='mask_cnt_news_item'
            limit = 4
        }

        wrap = <section><div class="container-fluid"><div class="row no-gutters news-teaserbox">|</div></div></section>

        renderObj = COA
        renderObj {

            wrap = |</div>

            10 = FILES
            10 {
                if.isTrue.field = tx_mask_cnt_news_item_teaser_bg

                references {
                    table = tt_content
                    # Seiten-ID
                    uid.dataWrap = {field:uid}
                    fieldName = tx_mask_cnt_news_item_teaser_bg
                }

                renderObj = TEXT
                renderObj.data = file:current:publicUrl
                renderObj.wrap = <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 news-tb-item" style="background-image: url('/|');">
            }

            15 = TEXT
            15 {
                if.isFalse.field = tx_mask_cnt_news_item_teaser_bg
                value = <div class="col-xl-6 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 news-tb-item">
            }

            20 = TEXT
            20 {
               wrap = <div class="news-tb-item-head">|</div>
                field = header
            }

            25 = CONTENT
            25 {
                wrap = <div class="categories">|</div>

                table = sys_category
                select {
                    # ID der Seite, auf der die Kategorien angelegt sind
                    pidInList = 0
                    join = sys_category_record_mm ON (sys_category_record_mm.uid_local=sys_category.uid)
                    where = sys_category_record_mm.tablenames='tt_content' AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = ###recorduid###
                    markers {
                        recorduid.field = uid
                    }
                }

                renderObj = TEXT
                renderObj.field = title
                renderObj.wrap = <li class="category {field:title}">|</li>
                renderObj.insertData = 1
            }

            30 = TEXT
            30 {
                wrap = <div class="news-tb-item-sub">|</div>
                field = subheader
            }

            40 = FILES
            40 {

                references {
                    table = tt_content
                    # Seiten-ID
                    uid.dataWrap= {field:uid}
                    fieldName = image
                }
                renderObj = IMAGE
                renderObj {
                    file.import.data = file:current:uid
                    file.crop.data = file:current:crop
                    file.treatIdAsReference = 1
                    altText.data = file:current:title
                    params =
                    wrap = |
                }

            }

            50 = TEXT
            50 {
                field = bodytext
            }

            60 = TEXT
            60 {
                value = Weiter
                lang.en = Read
                wrap = <div class="morelink-wrapper">|</div>

                typolink {
                    parameter.field =  pid
                    ATagParams =  class="morelink"
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Subpages?
You build a selection on `tt_content`, so you have all CEs of page 17.
maybe you mean

```
lib.newsteaser.20.table = pages
```

---

**If you select pages:**

Your marker definition access the pages record of the current page (`TSFE`) but you need the uid of the pages record which is your current context (`renderObj`).

So the correct marker definition should be:

```
pageuid.field = uid
```

---

**otherwise (select tt_content)**:

you need to use relations to your current record `tt_content`:

```
   where = sys_category_record_mm.tablenames='tt_content' AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = ###recorduid###
   markers.recorduid.field = uid
```

---

**or you select tt_content from subpages** (I don't know how you get records from subpages as you nowhere have selected subpages) and the categories are stored to the pages)

```
   where = sys_category_record_mm.tablenames='pages' AND sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign = ###pageuid###
   markers.pageuid.field = pid
```

the page of the tt_content record is stored in field `pid`

---

**How does TYPO3 store it's data?**

TYPO3 stores it's data in different tables. The main table is `pages` for the pages which build a website. These pages are structured in a tree. not all pages represent individual frontend pages. each record in TYPO3 is stored 'into' one page (assigned to a `pages`record). There exist one special 'page' which is no real page and which has no `pages`record. It's the root of the page tree and could be identified with a page with the uid 0. `uid`stands for 'unique identifier' and is a field in every data record. for identifying the page assigned to an record each data record has a field `pid` (page Id).
As also `pages`records have a field `pid` it gives the tree structure. each page has a parent, and the root page has the (pseudo-)page 0 as parent.
In a `pages`record a lot of information are stored, but normaly no content. (You could store background images, visuals or special preview images and also SEO information like a description or abstract in a `pages`record)
For content there exist a table `tt_content`. Here you store texts, (references to) images, or plugin configuration which control e.g. the rendering of other records.

For teasers of pages you can be realized in two kinds:
1. all information for the teaser is stored in the `pages`record
2. you use the content of the page, meaning: get information of `tt_content`records  in that page

a typical scenario where you use teasers is the listing of news: show the headline and abstract or intro with an image, which link to the detail view with the full text.

---

Your code reminds to this scenario and has nothing to do with a menu of pages represented by teasers.

This I would build with typoscript in this way:
build a menu object (maybe `special = directory`)
for each menuitem replace the default link with a `before` object, where you use the other fields of the *current* `pages`record to build a link consisting of preview image, page title, page abstract.

```
lib.teaserMenu = HMENU
lib.teasermenu {
    special = directory
    special.value = 123

    1 = TMENU
    1 {
      // remove normal link
      doNotShowLink = 1

      // build it by myself:
      before.cObject = COA
      before.cObject {
        stdWrap.wrap = <div class="teaser">|</div>
        stdWrap.typolink.field = uid

        10 = FILES
        10 {
          :
        }

        20 = TEXT
        20.field = title
        20.wrap = <h3>|</h3>

        30 = TEXT
        30.field = abstract
        30.wrap = <p>|</p>

        :
      }
   }
```

Comment: Hi Bernd, thanks for your help! I've added my complete code.  The reason why I selected `tt_content` is that I only want to display the contents of certain fields of the subpages in the teaser. Is it also possible to access the fields of the subpages via `pages`? Unfortunately, both of your examples for tt_content do not work with my code.

Comment: maybe you need to understand how TYPO3 works and how it stores data. I enhanced my answer.